# Does it change anything to write one semicolon or more at the end of a line in C++

Tags: c++

like in this case:

```
void function(){
...
uint8_t type = some_func(arg);;
...
}
```

I know semicolons are end of statements in c++ but writing multiple semicolons will it affect anything like maybe a tiny bit of processing time?

Comment: It does not but watchout with loops`for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i); { /* some code */ }` Will execute nothing ten times. Next it will execute some code once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can affect things. For instance, this if statement is ill-formed

```
if(foo())
  bar();;
else
  baz();
```

The extra semi-colon introduces an empty statement. The statement does nothing, but it breaks the association of the `else` to the `if`. Naturally, it's common wisdom to make judicious use of curly braces (`{}`) for compound statements for such reasons (and so this will likely only rarely occur in good code base). But since you did ask, that's one way the extra sem-colon can affect a parse.

As for processing time, assuming the program is well-formed. You will see no effect from an empty statement.

Comment: I actually knew about multiple semicolons in `if` and `else` statements or in loops, but this 
"As for processing time, assuming the program is well-formed. You will see no effect from an empty statement."
was useful, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Such a semicolon introduces a null-statement that has no effect.

You can use a null statement for example in a loop when the body of a loop is empty.

Here is a loop to set a pointer to point to the terminating zero of a string.

```
char *p = s;
for ( ; *p; ++p );
```

In C you need to use a null statement after a label when the label precedes a declaration because in C labels may not be placed before declarations.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const unsigned int N = 10;
    unsigned int i = 1;

    L:; 
    unsigned long long int square = i * i;

    printf( "%u\t%2llu\n", i, square );

    if ( ++i < N ) goto L;

    return 0;
}
```

Pay attention to the construction

```
L:;
```

Very often beginners make an error when they by mistake place a semicolon after a loop. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int main() 
{
    const char * s = "hello";
    const char *p = s;

    for ( ; *p; ++p );
    {
        std::cout << char( std::toupper( ( unsigned char )*p ) );
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Instead of outputting the sequence of characters `"HELLO"` the program outputs nothing.

*Similarly to the semicolon some C++ constructions accept a redundant comma. For example in a braced list of initializers.

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, };
                  ^^
```

However you may not place such a comma in the parameter declaration list

```
void f( int x1, int x2, int x3, );
                            ^^^^ compilation error
```

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon after another semicolon (or after if (...), after for(...), and so on) introduces a statement which does nothing.  It can be harmful, e.g. in the following:

```
if (x > 0)
  std::cout << "x is positive";;
else
  std::cout << "x is negative or zero";
```

Which is the same as

```
if (x > 0)
  std::cout << "x is positive";
;
else
  std::cout << "x is negative or zero";
```

The second semicolon ends if-block, making the following else "an orphan" (else without if), causing compile error.

You should avoid extra semicolons.